# Dexguard security during debugging

Tags: android, logcat, dexguard

i am using Dexguard in my android application to protect from
        reverse engineering.Now in my application which is very big ,i have
        used several places System.out.println in many classes in which i am
        printing my server URL to debugg for my ease.Now when i am releasing
        this application ,and this apk i am giving to other developers ,they
        can see all the System.out.println things in their logcat. how
        should i avoid that. This has serious issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't be using `System.out.println` directly everywhere. Use your own wrapper class for logging.

In dexguard/proguard you can use [`assumenosideeffects`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html) for removing codes that are unnecessary for release.

So for `System.out.print` you can add following in your dexguard rules.

```
 -assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream {
     public void println(%);
     public void println(**);
 }
```

But this is risky as this class might be used for purposes other than logging.

Fastest way for you would be to use `android.util.Log` in place of `System.out.print`  and then add following

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

See [proguard docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#logging)

Comment: i have written it so many places in my application .Is there any way to encrypt them or disable them while releasing apk ??

Comment: Isn't this what @vKashyap has suggested? adding these snippets to your proguard/dexguard config file and it will remove them from your compiled release code. have you tried it?

Comment: could you also tell me how to encrypt resourece folders in dexguard.it is not working . i can get easily my layout files when i decompile my apk

Answer (score 2):

good answer by @vKashyap, you might also want to add this as well...

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.lang.Exception {
    public void printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: could you also tell me how to encrypt resourece folders in dexguard.it is not working . i can get easily my layout files when i decompile my apk?

Comment: This would be more appropriate to raise another question and/ or contacting dexguard support. However I guess do you really care about layout files?